# Not updating, Getting installed location every time

Tags: android, google-maps, location

I am calling location update service in background, and storing lat-long in preference

- I am using this lat-long to updating current location
- I can able to store lat-long in preference, and also lat-long is getting updated
- But when I run app, I am getting my current marker on app installed location, not where I am (my current location).

Code:

```
  mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();
        createLocationRequest();

protected void createLocationRequest() {
        mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();

        mLocationRequest.setInterval(UPDATE_INTERVAL);
        mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(FASTEST_INTERVAL);
        mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
    }

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

    MarkerOptions mp = new MarkerOptions();
    mp.position(new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()));
    mp.title("my position");

    googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

    if (currentMarker != null) {
        currentMarker.remove();

    }

  dlat = Double.parseDouble(new String(preferenceHelper.getWalkerLatitude()));
     dlong = Double.parseDouble(new String(preferenceHelper.getWalkerLongitude()));

    Log.e("lat-lon",dlat+""+dlong);

    currentMarker = googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(
            new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude())).title("Your Location"));

}
```

- Don't know where I am wrong

Comment: what do you mean by `on app installed location` ? do you want to use location which is stored in preferences?

Comment: first time app installed location, everytime my current location marker is showing installed location position on map

Comment: as you are adding marker inside `onLocationChanged` method using `location` parameter, where it always shows the your current location only. if you want to show location which you have stored in preference then read values from preferences and create marker.

Comment: how to do that, if i fetch lat-long from preference it is throwing nullpointer ,java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                                     at java.lang.StringToReal.parseDouble(StringToReal.java:244)

Comment: post the code, how you are adding lat-lng to preferences.

Comment: check my updated question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109392/discussion-between-bharat-and-risk).